# Calculadora de Expressões - Problema na quebra da expressão

Tags: java

Estou fazendo faculdade e tenho que fazer uma Calculadora de expressões em *java*, ou seja, basicamente se você escrever (5+5)/2 ou qualquer coisa parecida, ela tem que te dar o resultado correto.

Não tive problemas com o uso de pilhas e filas, mas me deparei com um problema na hora de quebrar a minha expressão. Segue o método e a exception que me ocorreu:

```
private static String[] quebraExressao(String expressao)
{
    expressao = expressao.replaceAll(" ", "").replaceAll("", " ");
            String regex = "[0-9]";
            String[] elementos = expressao.split(" ");
            String[] elementos_retorno = new String[elementos.length];
            int j = 0;

            for (int i =0; i < elementos.length; i++)
            {
                if (elementos[i].matches(regex))
                {
                    if (elementos[i+1].matches(regex))
                    {
                        elementos_retorno[j] = elementos[i] + elementos[i+1];
                        i++;
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        elementos_retorno[j] = elementos[i];
                    }
                }
                else 
                {
                    elementos_retorno[j] = elementos[i];
                }

                j++;
            }

    return elementos_retorno;
}
```

E por fim recebi essa exception

> Insira a expressao:5+5
>   Expressao: 5+5
>
> java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4
>   0.0   at calculadorapoo.Expressao.quebraExressao(Expressao.java:199)  at calculadorapoo.Expressao.calcular(Expressao.java:63)     at
>   calculadorapoo.CalculoPolones.calcula(CalculoPolones.java:14)     at
>   calculadorapoo.CalculadoraPOO.main(CalculadoraPOO.java:18) CONSTRUÍDO
>   COM SUCESSO (tempo total: 5 segundos)

Estou usando o netbeans para fazer meu programa e não entendi muito bem onde o meu array estourou.

Gostaria de saber qual a melhor solução possível, estou aprendendo java há pouco tempo. Caso precisem do resto do programa, posso postar aqui. Obrigado.

EDITADO:
Consegui resolver o problema, porém agora estou com problema de NullPointer. Segue o código e o erro:

```
 public Double calcular() throws Exception 
{
int tamanhoFila = this.expressao.trim().length();
Fila fila = new Fila<>(tamanhoFila);
Pilha pilha = new Pilha<>(tamanhoFila);
String regex = "[0-9]";

String[] elementos = quebraExressao(this.expressao.trim());
for (String token : elementos)
{
        if (!token.equals(""))
        {
    if (token.matches(regex))   // se for numero
    {
                fila.emfila(token);
    }
    else    // se for operador
    {
                if (pilha.isVazia())
                {
        pilha.insere(token);
                }
                else 
                {
        String ultimoOperador = pilha.getUltimoElemento().toString();

        if (Tabela.devoDesempilhar(ultimoOperador.charAt(0), token.charAt(0)))
        {
                        if (token.equals(")"))
                        {
            while(!pilha.getUltimoElemento().equals("("))
            {
                                fila.emfila(pilha.retira());
            }
                                pilha.retira(); // para retirar o (
                        }
                        else 
                        {
            while(Tabela.devoDesempilhar(ultimoOperador.charAt(0), token.charAt(0)))
            {
                                fila.emfila(pilha.retira());
                                if (pilha.isVazia())
                                {
                pilha.insere(token);
                break;
                                }
                                else 
                ultimoOperador = pilha.getUltimoElemento().toString();
            }
                        }
        }
        else 
        {
                        pilha.insere(token);
        }
                }

    }
        }
}
```

Aparentemente ocorreu em dois lugares; ainda não sei se é por causa do primeiro mesmo, mas vou colocar o outro método.

```
public double calcula(String expressao)
{
double resultado = 0.0;

Expressao exp = new Expressao(expressao);

try 
    {
System.out.println("Expressao: " + expressao);
resultado = exp.calcular();

} 
    catch (Exception e) 
{
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
}

return resultado;
}
```

Aqui vai o NULLPOINTER e sua localidade

> Insira a expressao:5+5
>   Expressao: 5+5
>   java.lang.NullPointerException
>   0.0
>       at calculadorapoo.Expressao.calcular(Expressao.java:66)
>       at calculadorapoo.CalculoPolones.calcula(CalculoPolones.java:14)
>       at calculadorapoo.CalculadoraPOO.main(CalculadoraPOO.java:18)
>   CONSTRUÍDO COM SUCESSO (tempo total: 2 segundos)

Comment: Ainda não sei o problema, mas já adianto que seu array não estourou, a exceção `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` ocorre quando você tenta acessar um índice inexistente.

Comment: Acredito que na linha `if (elementos[i+1].matches(regex))` o índice `i+1` pode não existir. Antes dessa verificação, verifica se `i+1 < elementos.length`. Talvez só isso já resolva o seu problema.

Comment: Então basta colocar if(i+1 < elementos.length) e depois disso coloca o resto?

Comment: Seu regex só verifica se a primeira letra é dígito. Melhor colocar _String regex = "[0-9]+";_, mas só se aplica se a calculadora receber números com mais de um dígito.

Comment: Muito Obrigado João, a calculadora recebe sim mais de dois digitos!

Comment: Onde é a linha 66? Ela é a causa do nullpointer.

Comment: Diego F a Linha 66 é o começo do for

Answer (score 1):

Um colega meu fez uma calculadora em Java e utilizou um jeito diferente do seu. Ele usou um método chamado "eval" que transforma uma string em código executável para Javascript. Vou mostrar um exemplo:

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
    ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("nashorn");

    String teste = "print((5-2) * 3);";
    try 
    {
     engine.eval(teste);
    } 
    catch (ScriptException e)
    {
     e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

> No console vai aparecer o resultado **9**.

Não sei se isso responde sua pergunta, mas espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Então, estou sabendo sobre o eval , porem não foi me permitido usar =/

Comment: Entendi, que pena.

Comment: Mas caso consiga me ajudar, estou com erro de NullPointer no meu for xD

Comment: Qual é a linha 66 do código?

Comment: for (String token : elementos)

Comment: Bom, não sei se é isso, mas tente o seguinte: for(int i = 0; i < elementos.lenght; i++), ai teria que mudar o resto da lógica do seu programa.

Comment: Para não precisar alterar o restante do código pode fazer assim após o `for` sugerido pelo @Douglas: `for(int i = 0; i < elementos.lenght; i++) { String token = elementos[i]; }`